# Java/ Spring app get stuck after Tomcat deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I work with a Java/Spring Mvc web app for developing a Bitcoin wallet. After the deployment the app gets stuck and nothing happens. I mean the landing page opens in the localhost. Afterwards, It should have some progress towards synchronization and button/dropdown menus should be active. There are no errors. The only logs I get is some `WARNNING` and `INFO`,

```
[2017-06-28 11:25:03,820] Artifact BitcoinWalletApp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-06-28 11:25:03,820] Artifact BitcoinWalletApp:war exploded: Deploy took 6,195 milliseconds
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator: 06/28/2017 11:25:04 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

28-Jun-2017 11:12:49.818 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/manager]
28-Jun-2017 11:12:49.845 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = spring Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "50" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
28-Jun-2017 11:12:49.845 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = spring Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
28-Jun-2017 11:12:49.855 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/manager] has finished in [36] ms
```

In the `database-context.xml` file, the `JNDI` config is provided,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <context:component-scan base-package="mobi.puut.database">
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans profile="production">
        <context:property-placeholder
                location="classpath:mobi/puut/config/jdbc.properties"/>

        <!--<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"-->
              <!--destroy-method="close">-->
            <!--<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"></property>-->
            <!--<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>-->
            <!--<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>-->
            <!--<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>-->
        <!--</bean>-->

        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource"
                         expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        </jee:jndi-lookup>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>-->
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>

            <property name="packagesToScan" value="mobi.puut.entities"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


        <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
              class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
        </bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

In the `web.xml`, the database reference is provided as following,

```
<description>Spring Database</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/spring</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

In the `Tomcat`, the `Resource` info is provided from `conf/context.xml` as following,

```
<Resource name="jdbc/spring" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="testname" password="testpassword"
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet"/>
```

I can provide more info if required. What's the issue and how to solve it?

UPDATE

I have changed attributes in conf/context.xml as described in log: maxTotal instead of maxActive and maxWaitMillis instead of maxWait and the `WARNING` goes away. It still get stuck though.

```
28-Jun-2017 15:54:05.451 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-9.0.0.M21/webapps/manager]
28-Jun-2017 15:54:05.486 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/Tomcat-9.0.0.M21/webapps/manager] has finished in [34] ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change attributes in `conf/context.xml` as described in log: `maxTotal` instead of `maxActive` and `maxWaitMillis` instead of `maxWait`?

Comment: Yes, the WARNING goes away. I shut down everything and restarted. Also, deleted the `temp` and `work` files in the `Tomcat` directory. Now it goes away.